# Combinatorics - numbers of partitions of $k$ vs $k+1$

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

How does the number of partitions of $k$ relate to the number of partitions
of $k + 1$ whose smallest part is one?

I used to think it would be similar to prime numbers since the number of partitions of $1,2,3,4,5$ goes $1,2,3,5,7$ respectively but as $k$ increases, the number of partitions get much larger and eventually non-prime. However, I don't know how to answer this question on how $k$ compares to $k+1$.

Comment: Take any partition of $k$ and add a 1 to it. You get a partition of $k+1$ with smallest part 1. You can do the reverse, so both numbers are equivalent.

Comment: I see! That makes so much sense